# Customizing myLocationButton in Jetpack Compose Map Compose library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-compose

I'm working on an application that utilizes Jetpack Compose and the Map Compose library. However, I'm facing limitations with the default myLocationButton provided by the library. I would like to customize this button by changing its icon, adjusting its position, and potentially adding other customizations. I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this functionality within the Map Compose library. Alternatively, I would like to know if there is a method to invoke the standard myLocationButton while utilizing a custom implementation.

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
[This is what the standard button looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxsPN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
@Composable
fun MyFab2(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {

    val iconPainter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.current_location_icon)

    FloatingActionButton(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        content()
        Icon(
            painter = iconPainter,
            contentDescription = "Add FAB",
            tint = Color.Black,
        )
    }

}
```

//Then in a Box, for example:

```
 Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                    MyGoogleMap()

                    MyFab2(
                        onClick = { fabOnClick() },
                        content = {
                            // Add FAB content here
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(82.dp)
                            .padding(24.dp)
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                            .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                    )
                }
```

// You now can do whatever you like as you do with a simple FAB.
// So, then, what you get is this: [image]